# blank tkinter window when executing

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm coding a Tkinter, which much consist of a checkbox and File Menu containing Save Option.

Problem:
It comes in 2 tkinter instead of one. One is a blank GUI, and another consists of my checkbox, textbox, file and save.

How to avoid the blank GUI?

My code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
from tkFileDialog import askopenfile, asksaveasfile
import tkFileDialog

class myproject(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.textbox()
        self.checkbox2()
    def textbox(self):
        self.txt1 = Tkinter.Text(root, borderwidth=3, relief="sunken", height=4,width=55)
        self.txt1.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
        self.txt1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)
    def checkbox2(self): #self.checkbox
        checkbox = Tkinter.Checkbutton(root, text = " ")
        checkbox.grid(column=1,row=2)


    def file_save(self):
        f = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")


root = Tkinter.Tk()

menubar = Menu(root)
root.configure(menu=menubar)

filemenu = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=myproject.file_save)
app = myproject(None)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why is the master of txt1 root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reworked your code to make it work.

What was changed: You had 2 variables `root` and `app`, one of which was creating the blank window. I changed it to just use a single variable `root`, which is initialized to `myproject` at the start.

Instead of using `root` in your functions, I changed those to `self`, because `self` inherits from `Tkinter.Tk` as well.

And in the `__init__` function, I removed the variable `parent` which was unused.

Update: Also in the call to filemenu.add_command, it is changed to pass in root.file_save instead of myproject.file_save. Thanks PM 2Ring.

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
from tkFileDialog import askopenfile, asksaveasfile
import tkFileDialog

class myproject(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.textbox()
        self.checkbox2()
    def textbox(self):
        self.txt1 = Tkinter.Text(self, borderwidth=3, relief="sunken", height=4,width=55)
        self.txt1.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
        self.txt1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)
    def checkbox2(self): #self.checkbox
        checkbox = Tkinter.Checkbutton(self, text = " ")
        checkbox.grid(column=1,row=2)
    def file_save(self):
        f = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")

root = myproject()

menubar = Menu(root)
root.configure(menu=menubar)

filemenu = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=root.file_save)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks PM 2Ring! I missed the one you mentioned, and now fixed it above.